# ASP.NET with AcuXDBC problems

Tags: asp.net, iis, cobol

We are currently running an ASP.NET MVC site that connects to a COBOL database through ACUGT. We are using ACUXDBC 8.01 drivers.

The machine with the ASP.NET site is on a machine that has Windows Server Standard 2008 with SP2, IIS 7, 4 GB of RAM.

About twice a day the website stops working for one of the 2 reasons:

1. We get the error that says
   “System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005):
   Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
   {BFBBB600-C4DB-11D2-B11B-74F606C10000} failed due to the following
   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).”, where we have to restart
   the server.
2. IIS gets the processor to 100% and we have to stop the
   process and everything gets back to normal.

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Below is the config section for ACU.

[image]

Comment: I think best to take it up with vendor providing the product (Micro Focus?). It i  not a question about programming, so is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, perhaps another Stack Exchange site, but how much experience of ACU* will be attending, I don't know.

Comment: I have posted this on the micro focus forum as well and I am waiting for response.

Answer (score 0):

Version 8.0.1 of AcuXDBC is quite early (it was first introduced in version 7.4.0). The latest version (which I've been evaluating for a couple of months) is 9.2.2.

It sounds like that version of the AcuXDBC server has a memory leak. Versions [9.0.0](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/ACU/900/extend900ReleaseNotes.pdf) and [9.1.2](http://supportline.microfocus.com/Documentation/books/ACU/912/extend912releasenotes.pdf) had quite a few enhancements relating to performance/memory.

Have you actually talked to your MicroFocus support representative? It has to be a licensed product, so you would be entitled to support from them.

Comment: It is licensed, but the license expired. We are investigating now the queries we are running and we will try to optimize them. I will try to see if we can upgrade to 9.2.2.